# Is there any Flink metric that shows number of keys in state with hashmap state backend?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, metrics

I'm using Apache Flink 1.14 with RocksDB as the state backend, and I thinking of migrating the state backend to Hashmap to improve latency.
The main drawback of this approach is that RocksDB exposes a metric showing the [estimated number of keys in the state](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#state-backend-rocksdb-metrics-estimate-num-keys), and with hashmap state backend it seems that I'll lose this capability.

Is there any way to expose/implement this metric with the hashmap state backend?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this with metrics, but an alternative would be to build tooling that uses the State Processor API to process savepoints and report this information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DavidAnderson, that sounds like an interesting idea. I'll try that out.
In the meantime I've been running some tests and I found that having hashmap as the state backend with the property `state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.estimate-num-keys: 'true'` still produces the number of keys in the state. Any idea how that works?

Comment: No idea. Does the metric still appear to produce meaningful results?

Comment: Yes, I tested it by producing 50K keys to memory and I saw it increasing at the same rate that I was producing messages.

Comment: To give an update. The configuration and the actual code were not correct. I declared the state backend via configuration, but the code had a bug that was forcing RocksDB as a state backend, which explains the metric still working. I fixed the bug and now the metric has disappeared. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I had made myself a note to double-check on this, but it seemed quite unlikely.